# How to share object tree with process fork?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I don't have much experience with multithreading, and I'm trying to get something like the below working:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

class Test(Process):

    def __init__(self, tree):
        super().__init__()
        self.tree = tree

    def run(self):
        # infinite loop which does stuff to the tree
        self.tree.children[1] = Node()
        self.tree.children[2] = Node()

x = Node()
t = Test(x)
t.start()
print(x.children)  # random access to tree
```

I realize this shouldn't (and doesn't) work for a variety of very sensible reasons, but I'm not sure how to get it *to* work.  Referring to the documentation, it seems that I need to do something with Managers and Proxies, but I honestly have no idea where to start, or whether that is actually what I'm looking for.  Could someone provide an example of the above that works?

Comment: Do you want multithreading (one process, several threads, shared address space) or multiprocessing (several processes, no shared address space)? What's the higher-level problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want multithreading, but sidestepping Python's GIL problem.  Maybe I'm asking for too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiprocessing` has limited support for [implicitly shared objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), which can even share lists and dicts.

In general, `multiprocessing` is [shared-nothing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms) (after the initial fork) and relies on explicit communication between the processes. This adds overhead (how much really depends on the kind of interaction between the processes), but neatly avoids a lot of the pitfalls of multithreaded programming. The high-level building blocks of `multiprocessing` favor master/slave models (esp. the [Pool class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)), with masters handing out work items, and slaves operating on them, returning results.

Keeping state in sync across several processes may, depending how often they change, incur a prohibitive overhead.

**TL;DR**: It can be done, but probably shouldn't.

```
import time, multiprocessing

class Test(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, manager):
        super().__init__()
        self.quit = manager.Event()
        self.dict = manager.dict()

    def stop(self):
        self.quit.set()
        self.join()

    def run(self):
        self.dict['item'] = 0
        while not self.quit.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)
            self.dict['item'] += 1

m = multiprocessing.Manager()
t = Test(m)
t.start()
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1.2)
    print(t.dict)
t.stop()
```

The `multiprocessing` examples show how to create proxies for more [complicated objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#examples), which should allow you to implement the tree structure in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what you want is actual multithreading, rather than multiprocessing. With threads rather than processes, you can do precisely that, since threads run in the same process, sharing all memory and therefore data with each other.